# Why is my regex is not matching?

Tags: java, regex

I have some lines in a text file like this:

```
==Text==
```

I'm trying to match the start, using this:

```
line.matches("^==[^=]")
```

However, this returns false for every line... little help?

Comment: What language is this in? If it's Java, pretty sure it tries to match the entire line. This would fail, because the [^=] would eventually not match, making the entire line not match, returning false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches` automatically anchors the regex, so the regex has to match the whole string. Try:

```
line.matches("==[^=].*")
```

Answer (score 7):

As I remember, method `matches()` searches for exact match only.

Comment: This is true, and the documentation could be a lot clearer about it -- http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `String.startsWith("==");` if it is something simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
try line.matches("^==[^=]*==$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `line.matches("^==(.+?)==\\s*$")`

Answer (score 0):

.matches only returns true if the entire line matches. In your case, the line would have to start with '==' and contain exactly one character that was not equals. If you are looking to match that string for the whole line:

> line.matches("==[^=]*==")

Comment: This should produce a match of == followed by arbitrary non-equals characters, followed by another ==.

Comment: Bummer, minor edits moved my answer to look newer than it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `matches` will only return true if the entire line matches the regex.  In your case it won't.  To use `matches` you will need to extend your regex (using wildcards) to match to the end of the line.  Alternatively you could just use `Matcher.find()` method to match substrings of the line